# ¿Cómo eliminar contenido creado dinámicamente en Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Estuve desarrollando una App en la que al apretar un botón, este debe crear otros botones según los elementos de una lista. Para esto utilizo el siguiente código:

```
private void BtnPartes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (var c in ListaClientes)
     {
          string nombre = c.cmCompanyCode.ToString() + " - " + c.cmCompanyName;

          Button btnCliente = new Button();
          btnCliente.Text = nombre;
          btnCliente.Clicked += BtnCliente_Click;

          StackLayoutBody.Children.Add(btnCliente);
     }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que antes de hacer el foreach, debería borrar todos los botones creados anteriormente, de lo contrario es muy probable que se dupliquen algunos.

No se si explico bien cual es el problema.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está resuelto el problema. Con esto funciona bien.

```
foreach (var item in StackLayoutBody.Children.ToList())
{
     if (item.GetType() == btnPartes.GetType() && ((Button)item).Text != "Traer Partes Pendientes")
     {
          StackLayoutBody.Children.Remove(item);
     }
}
```

Con el `item.GetType() == btnPartes.GetType()` lo que hice fue verificar que el elemento sea un boton y con el `((Button)item).Text != "Traer Partes Pendientes")` casteo el item para que sea un elemento del tipo Button y me fijo que el texto no sea el del boton principal de la ventana.

Luego de todo eso se eliminan todos los botones.